# "reverse" regular expression with JavaScript(node.js)

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

With regular expression like this `/\w/` I can match strings like `a`, `q`.
Is there any idiomatic way to generate all the strings which match some regex in JS?

Don't think about infinite cases. I just want to describe some sets of possible symbols briefly.

something meaningful instead of

`` var s = ' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~' ``

Comment: This is a hard problem to solve. As there are infinite regular expressions that have infinite strings they match (for example `/a+/`).

Comment: That program would very easy not halt anymore, a `\w+` is all you need to generate an "infinite" amount of strings.

Comment: Instead of _all the strings_ are you looking for a representative test set? That doesn't make the problem any easier but maybe there are solutions.

Comment: you could make your own regexp parser-like thing, where `\w` would stand-in for the set of chars it matches. then you can randomly/sequentially string along all those stand-ins to generate matching text sets. in that sense, full RegExp vocab would not be needed, you can build on as needed.

Comment: Thanks. Added some details to the question

Comment: For only a description you should turn to https://regex101.com/. There is an "Explanation".

Comment: There is a [PHP library](https://github.com/icomefromthenet/ReverseRegex) who tries this.

Comment: And [Python *xeger*](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xeger), too. Oh, just came across [**randexp**](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js?) for JS. *randexp will generate a random string that matches a given RegExp Javascript object.*

Comment: Another [link](http://regldg.com/tryit.php) (regldg): This is a C based solution available for download and as web service (with restricted size of output) to test the functionality online. I have no affiliation whatsoever with the project.

Answer (score 9):

You can try the [*randexp* library](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js?):

> `Randexp` will generate a random string that matches a given RegExp Javascript object

See the demo:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = new RandExp(/\w/).gen();
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>" + new RandExp(/\w/).gen();
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>" + new RandExp(/[for]{3}/).gen();
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>" + new RandExp(/I like (cats|dogs|mice)/).gen();
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/fent/randexp.js/releases/download/v0.4.1/randexp.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You'd need to generate any chunk of text and test against the regexp. It is not possible nowadays, I think, you'd have to wait for ages. Why do you need to get *all* possible variations? You just need that for testing, don't you?

Comment: Again, that is not possible.

Comment: Why? I don't need to describe infinite cases. I just need to say `/[\w\{\}}]/`
instead of writing string like
`abcdef ..... {}`

Comment: So, what prevents you from writing `/[\w{}]/` manually? Regexps are meant to *extract strings meeting specific patterns*, not the other way round. The "other way round" is testing regexps, and what I suggest in the answer meets this end, I believe.

Comment: I mean to say that using the regexp the way you want is something what regex is not supposed to do. Saying "it is not possible" I mean it is not that easy to re-construct the regex parser (although it is feasible) and try to produce all substrings using the Unicode sets. Just that means a lot of work, and without some considerable effort, that is rather a broad topic for this Q&A site.