# How to create a random string from a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I want to generate a random string form a regular expression.

example:

```
random_string(/^[0-9]{4}$/) //==> 7895
random_string(/^[0-9]{4}$/) //==> 0804
random_string(/^[0-9,A-Z]{4}$/) //==> 9ZE5
random_string(/^[0-9,A-Z]{4}$/) //==> 84D6
```

Comment: You have to parse the regex which is like reinventing the wheel. Why not making a function that accepts character ranges and then return a random string out of those ranges.

Comment: Also, see [“reverse” regular expression with JavaScript(node.js)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35799900/reverse-regular-expression-with-javascriptnode-js/35800226#35800226).

Comment: There is no programmatic way to generate random strings without setting up a state machine. But that is atomic. The inner doesn't know much about the outer. Result is, it can't be done. You could try to parse the expression yourself, know what each state needs, but its pathways are still unknown. Or, just throw  random text at an expression and see if it matches. That's the quickest way. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547777/how-to-create-a-random-string-from-a-regular-expression/43553196#43553196) for why not to use randexp.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a random string based on a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959850/generate-a-random-string-based-on-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take a look to [randexp.js](http://fent.github.io/randexp.js/), it does exactly what you want

```js
console.log(new RandExp(/^[0-9]{4}$/).gen());
console.log(new RandExp(/^[0-9]{4}$/).gen());
console.log(new RandExp(/^[0-9,A-Z]{4}$/).gen());
console.log(new RandExp(/^[0-9,A-Z]{4}$/).gen());
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/fent/randexp.js/releases/download/v0.4.3/randexp.min.js"></script>
```

Of course there are some limitations:

> Repetitional tokens such as *, +, and {3,} have an infinite max range.
>   In this case, randexp looks at its min and adds 100 to it to get a
>   useable max value. If you want to use another int other than 100 you
>   can change the max property in RandExp.prototype or the RandExp
>   instance.

Comment: This `randexp.min.js` is not to be trusted or used. I'd say there is more limitations than stated. Namely it gives results that are in error. Example: `console.log(new RandExp(/^((0(?:[1-9]|$)|1(?:[0-2]|$))(?::(?:([0-5])(?:([0-9])(?:\s([ap]m?)?)?)?)?)?)$/).gen());` spits out `0:` and `1:` which the regex won't match.

Comment: `/^[0-9,A-Z]{4}$/` could generate strings that include commas like `000,`. In case you want alphanumeric strings, just use `/[0-9A-Z]{4}/` instead.

Answer (score 6):

`rand` here will accepts a `length` which will be the length of the string, and a number of 2-items arrays, each determine a range boundaries. Then return a string which only consists of the characters in the ranges provided.

```js
function rand(length, ...ranges) {
  var str = "";                                                       // the string (initialized to "")
  while(length--) {                                                   // repeat this length of times
    var ind = Math.floor(Math.random() * ranges.length);              // get a random range from the ranges object
    var min = ranges[ind][0].charCodeAt(0),                           // get the minimum char code allowed for this range
        max = ranges[ind][1].charCodeAt(0);                           // get the maximum char code allowed for this range
    var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;        // get a random char code between min and max
    str += String.fromCharCode(c);                                    // convert it back into a character and append it to the string str
  }
  return str;                                                         // return str
}

console.log(rand(4, ["A", "Z"], ["0", "9"]));
console.log(rand(20, ["a", "f"], ["A", "Z"], ["0", "9"]));
console.log("Random binary number: ", rand(8, ["0", "1"]));
console.log("Random HEX color: ", "#" + rand(6, ["A", "F"], ["0", "9"]));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also have a try with [reregexp.js](https://github.com/suchjs/reregexp), it support many newest regex features:

- `\u` flag: e.g. `/[\u{30}-\u{39}\u{2c}\u{41}-\u{5a}]{4}/u`
- Named group: e.g. `/(?<named>[0-9,A-Z]{2})\k<named>/`
- Define a generator function and use the unicode property class: e.g. `/\p{Script=Hani}/u`

Here is a test:

```js
var re = new ReRegExp(/^[0-9,A-Z]{4}$/, {
    extractSetAverage: true // this config make the '0-9' has chance ten times than the ',',otherwise they both have equal chance.          
});
console.log(re.build());
console.log(re.build());
console.log(re.build());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/suchjs/reregexp@master/dist/reregexp.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When offering you own library please disclose that it is yours.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for your advice,i have changed the js file into a jsdelivr address :)