# Using JavaScript, how to generate a randm 11 char string following these param/rules? (L,L,L,L/N,L/N,N,N,N,N,N,N)

Tags: javascript, random, parameters, alphanumeric, generate

I am trying to figure out, using Javascript, how to generate a RANDOM 11 character string which requires a specific sequence of letters/numbers, in regards to position.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
*Example of what I need to be able to generate:*

**Key:**
**C** - Constant *(regardless of whether Alpha or Numeric Char; is NEVER randomized)*
**L** - Alpha Character
**N** - Numeric Character
**L/N** - Either Letter or Number acceptable

|#1.|#2.|#3.|#4.|#5.|#6.|#7.|#8.|#9.|#10|#11| 
|C..|C..|C..|L/N|L/N|N..|N...|N..|N...|N...|N...|

*generated string example:*
ABC1A123456
ABCAB859328
ABC41932013
ABCD2615982
ABCEF081799
ABC32701174
*etc...*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

This is what I've started with.. I have my first 3 characters (the constants) and I have the alphanumeric characters that i want eligible for the randomization of the remaining 8 char of the sequence. But what I don't have, and what I'm asking the community to help me with, is how to implement rules so that my script will only allow the randomized generated strings to follow the description I've given above.

I hope I've explained everything clearly. =\

```
function makeid() {
  var text = "LJH";
  var possible = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}


function main() {
    document.getElementById("number").value = makeid();
    document.getElementById("button").click();
}

setInterval(function() {
    main();
}, speed);
```

Comment: Where is the key provided? I don't see it in your `makeid` function, can you give a specific example of a key input, so we can see what its syntax is like? (is it a parameter?)

Comment: Your code is adding eight alphanumeric characters. Amending it to only add numbers for the last six characters seems very simple based on the existing code: use two loops and change `possible` in between.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a random string from a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547777/how-to-create-a-random-string-from-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1):

#### Live example adapting your code:

```js
makeid();

function makeid() {
  var text = "ABC";
  var numbers = "1234567890";
  var alphanumbers = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    text += alphanumbers.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alphanumbers.length));
  }
  for (var i = 2; i < 8; i++) {
    text += numbers.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length));
  }
  console.log(text);
}
```

Divide your dictionary in two:

1. `var numbers` (Numbers only)
2. `var alphanumbers` (Alphanumeric)

Then, make your id with two interactions:

- First interaction will concatenate 2 alphanumeric chars
- Second iteration will concatenate last 6 positions only with numbers

Comment: The code is very simple and self-explanatory, there is a fixed initial text, the fourth and fifth position of the string is alphanumeric and the rest is numeric, exactly what was asked in the question.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks ℛɑƒæĿ.

Comment: I understand it's self explanatory, but to someone who was having trouble writing it, an explanation is often helpful

Comment: @RawstyleS It's A pleasure help someone like you! Regards!

Comment: @JuanMendes Really, I agree, I put an explanation to endorse the answer. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: @RawstyleS Please accept an answer if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```js
function r(base, len){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (base**len))
    .toString(base)
    .padStart(len, 0)
}

function makeid() {
  return "LJH" + r(36, 2).toUpperCase() + r(10, 6);
}

for(let i=0; i<100; ++i) 
  console.log(makeid());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

But careful with the ranges, JS Numbers still, only have 53 bit of precision. Luckily, nowadays the generated random numbers also contain 53 "random" bits.